# Can I retrieve or deploy profile settings for managed package components other than objects and fields?

Tags: managed-package, deployment, permissions

This is a great question and answer that shows how to retrieve profile settings for managed package components, but the answers only seem to apply to objects and fields.

[Deploying Profiles / Permission Sets that include object & field permissions for Managed Objects](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4925/deploying-profiles-permission-sets-that-include-object-field-permissions-for)

The original questioner posted this further question as an answer. What's the answer to this question? Can I use a similar trick to deploy profile permissions for managed classes, pages etc?

> I was able to successfully deploy the object & field permissions for
>   managed objects through eclipse but I'm having trouble moving the
>   following:
>
> - **Apex Class** permissions for managed apex
> - **VisualForce** page permissions for managed apex
> - **Tab Visibility** (running into problems with Permission Set tab visibility seems as though eclipse doesn't allow you to deploy tab visibility at all in eclipse)
> - **App Assignments**